# MongoDB native Query in JPA

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa

What i wanted to do is to write method that when given a imageID and AnnotationID deletes annotation from the annotation array in specific Image.

My data structure looks more or less like this:

```
IMAGE:
{
ID,
name,
annotations{
    id
    ...
    }
}
```

I was able to implement it by actually doing like this (getting image, update the list, then update an image).

```
Image image = imageRepository.readImageByName(name);
        Annotation[] annotations = image.getAnnotations();
        List<Annotation> annotationsToSave = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Annotation annotation:annotations){
            if(!annotation.get_id().equals(_id)){
                annotationsToSave.add(annotation);
            }
        }

        Annotation[] annotationsArrayToSave = 
        annotationsToSave.toArray(Annotation[]::new);

        image.setAnnotations(annotationsArrayToSave);
        imageRepository.save(image);
    }
```

My question is. Is there is any way i can put it in native query or MongoTemplate to mongodb that actually do the same thing i did in my code, but on the server side?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: So basicly we want to implement a method that will do this query:
<code>
collection.update(
  { name: name }, //name from parameter
  { $pull: { 'contact.annotation': { _id: id } } } // id from parameter
);
</code>
Question is how to put that query in Java :)